# c# splitting strings using string instead of char as seperator

Tags: c#

I have string `string text = "1.2788923 is a decimal number. 1243818 is an integer. ";` Is there a way to split it on the commas only ? This means to split on `". "` but not on `'.'`. When I try `string[] sentences = text.Split(". ");` I get method has invalid arguments error..

Comment: Use this overload of String.Split: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to  split it like:

```
string[] sentences = text.Split(new string[] { ". " },StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You will end up with two items in your string:

```
1.2788923 is a decimal number
1243818 is an integer
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Regex.Split`:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(text, @"\. ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The string(s) that you splitting on are expected to be in a separate array.

```
String[] s = new String[] { ". " };
String[] r = "1. 23425".Split(s, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions

```
public static void textSplitter(String text)
   {

  string pattern = "\. ";           

String[] sentences = Regex.Split(text, pattern);

}
```